# Why does this particular Javascript loop only work when reassigning a variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

So my goal is to create a function in Javascript that randomly places a few divs on the page. Ultimately, I'd like to fill these divs with pictures, so that it creates the idea of pictures being randomly thrown on a table. I came up with a for loop, and it works now, but I don't understand why it didn't work before.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var xvalue;
var yvalue;

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  xvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  yvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "frame");
  newDiv.style.top = yvalue+"px";
  newDiv.style.left = xvalue+"px";
  wrapper.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Before, I had moved this line:

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

to before the actual for loop. As it only serves to create a new div, I figured I might as well declare the variable outside of the loop. However, doing this led it to produce the same `div` *three* times over, on the same spot. Usually I understand why a fixed variable will produce the same results if placed outside the for loop, but here I don't see why.

Thanks in advance!

Daan

Comment: You can't understand why creating only one div creates only one div?

Comment: But it's a for loop no? And when I tell it to create a new div [i] times, shouldn't it then produce it this many times. Also, this doesn't answer my question which was why placing the createElement inside the loop changes results so radically

Comment: Cause you had a single div created for all the iterations. So you were manipulating the same div every single time when it was outside the loop.

Comment: If you place the code that creates the element outside the loop, then the loop will obviously have no effect on how many elements are created.

Comment: Here is a great video on scope and the compile stage in javascript.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRZri_CHqnA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put

```
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
```

outside the loop, you'll have just one object and manipulate it over three cycles. You won't have three objects...

By the way, move all `var` in your code to the top without assignments (see code below).

> Variable declarations are hoisted to the top!

[More about hoisting here.](https://www.sitepoint.com/back-to-basics-javascript-hoisting/)

Your code looks differently as it behaves. By putting all `var` to the top it looks the way it actually works, and that's far better (for understanding and debugging).

Your corrected code would be:

```
var i, newDiv, xvalue, yvalue, wrapper;

wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  xvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  yvalue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  newDiv.setAttribute("class", "frame");
  newDiv.style.top = yvalue + "px";
  newDiv.style.left = xvalue + "px";
  wrapper.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with the `var` comment. By not using var, you're declaring a variable in the global scope and that can lead to all kinds of trouble. If you need to put something on the global scope, you should be explicit about it and use `window.newDiv = ...`. But then it's likely there's better way to accomplish your objective without resorting to global. Also, in this particular example, OP wants `newDiv` to be scoped to the for loop. It also seems odd to me that the `newDiv` var will hang around as an arbitrary reference to the last div created.

Comment: No no no. I amended my answer because this is not what I meant. You should use `var` (or `let` in ES6+) but not in the middle of the code, because of hoisting. I did NOT mean to omit it completely. Please take a look at my code cleanup where all `var`s are on the first line.

Comment: By re-reading your comment I sense there's a misunderstanding. You cannot scope a `var` to a `for ()` loop because **JS has no block scoping, it only has function scoping**. Follow the hoisting link above for more information about what this is. If you don't like the orphaned newDiv reference just clean it up with a `newDiv = undefined;` or `delete newDiv;`.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the updated answer makes more sense. And I forgot about the lack of block scoping in ES5.

Comment: @gargantuan Yes, as you pointed out, even ES6 has *sadly* (or *luckily*?) no block scoping... for `var`. That's why we have `let` ;)